# BCP cannot read table created in the same transaction when executed from Control-M

Tags: sql-server, bcp

How to export global temp table using BCP when original process locks table for BCP?
We created our own exporting procedure where we provide SELECT or table_name and procedure stores data to global temp table, which then BCP utility exports.
It runs fine, but when we run it from BMC's Control-M system, there is schema modification lock on the table and procedure just waits for itself to unlock.
Static table(s) is not a good solution for us.

We tried using for example self linking linked server or index on all columns of global temp table.

Our current proposal is to add export to a queue which would then be exported asynchronously by another process.

Comment: Looks like Control-M starting a transaction before it runs your procedure.  Can you make it not do that?

Comment: Your are on point, unfortunately we are fighting for this more than a year now. Are you familiar with Control-M how to disable this?

Comment: The docs say there's an "Auto Commit" checkbox: https://documents.bmc.com/supportu/9.0.20/help/Plugins/en-US/DATABASE/Web_Help/index.htm#2177.htm

Comment: A wildcard could be sp_bindsession so the two share transaction space, but would be pretty far out there (if at all doable). Assumes they can pass the session context, btw. I would *not* go this route if there are other means. Note that the ##tempdb table is removed when the creating session/scope doesn't exist anymore, btw.

Comment: Are you using High-Availability Group? In this case you might run that on the second replica. Why do you need to run it from BMC's Control-M system? Cannot you just run that from the server that is hosting the database?

Comment: Yes we are, will try that. Control-M is orchestrating our processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up creating a permanent table and a job.

Table stores data as queue and procedure with insert is executed from Control-M with no issue.
Agent Job then reads the queue and executes BCP.